# Add hyperlink and formula within the same cell

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula

Is it possible to add a hyperlink and a formula in the same cell from the formula bar*? I'm trying to have a file link to the percentage but I need it to calculate the percent too.

This is the formula already in it:

`=IFERROR(P2/P4,"NA")`

But I'd also like to add:

`=HYPERLINK("..\..\MyFileA.xlsx","FileA")`

Comment: how are your percentage calculation and hyperlink related?  why do you need them both in the same cell?  how is it that you want this information displayed/used

Comment: I'd like to make it so if people click on the percent then they could see the source data. It's counting pass/fail data from a separate csv file. I would of just used the hyperlink menu in excel but I need Python to put write it in the cell.

Comment: so what you are asking for is that the "FRIENDLY DISPLAY NAME" of the hyperlink be your percentage and the link associated to that friendly name be your source data?

Comment: I changed my answer so that the file would not appear in the text - only the percentage.

Comment: @timthebomb you blew away your answer! BOOM! 8)

Comment: @ForwardEd all for getting people to the right answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [syntax](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f) for `HYPERLINK` is:

> HYPERLINK(link_location, [friendly_name])

So you want to put your descriptive stuff in the `friendly_name` parameter and just the link itself in the `link_location`. Per you example in the question the formula would read:

```
=HYPERLINK("..\..\MyFileA.xlsx",IFERROR(TEXT(P2/P4,"##.00%"),"NA")&" % - FileA")
```

Comment: if you are going to tack on the % symbol, would you also not need to multiply P2/P4*100?  I was thinking about doing that for my own answer but decided to keep it to the OP's original equation

Comment: LOL I thought you were going to edit in the *100 so the op would have some more variety to the answers.

Comment: @ForwardEd - ahhh go on then. I think that will work.

Comment: Thanks it works! For the percent I have Python change the cell format as part of the script before adding this formula.

Comment: @iOSecure if the hyper link puts the number in for the friendly name as a string, formatting the cell may not change the way the number is displayed.  I am not positive about this just thought of it as a possibility.

Comment: @Robin That is a nicer way then I was thinking to display that percentage to two decimal places only!

Answer (score 2):

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.ca",IFERROR(P2/P4,"NA"))
```

replace the web link with your file path